# Updated Query is not Working in hibernate

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have used :

> spring mvc-version:4.3.7 postgres:9.5 Tool:STS

**my dao:**

```
   @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void updatedivision(Division p) {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
         Query query = session.createQuery("update Division set name =:name where id = :id ");
         query.setParameter("name", p.getName());  
         query.setParameter("id", p.getId());
         int result = query.executeUpdate();    
         session.flush();

        System.out.println("Division updated successfully, Division Details=" + p.getName());
```

I want to update my database. But after entry in the form.But when I run the code, the updated value is received properly ( I have checked by printing the the value. ) But Table is not updated.

**My servlet-contet.xml**

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
>     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
>     xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
>     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
>         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">
>
>     <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
>         infrastructure -->
>
>   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
>     <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
>     <annotation-driven />
>
>     <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
>         up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
>     <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
>
>     <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
>         in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
>     <beans:bean
>         class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
>         <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
>         <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
>     </beans:bean>
>
>     <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
>         destroy-method="close">
>         <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
>         <beans:property name="url"
>             value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/firmvilldb" />
>         <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
>         <beans:property name="password" value="root" />
>     </beans:bean>
>
>     <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
>     <beans:bean id="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory"
>         class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
>         <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
>         <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
>             <beans:list>
>                 <beans:value>com.asha.farmvill.model.Division</beans:value>
>             </beans:list>
>         </beans:property>
>         <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
>             <beans:props>
>                 <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
>                 </beans:prop>
>                 <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
>                  <beans:prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">1</beans:prop>
>               <beans:prop key="hibernate.default-lazy">false</beans:prop>
>                 <beans:prop key="hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
>             </beans:props>
>         </beans:property>
>     </beans:bean>
>
>    <beans:bean id="divisionDao" class="com.asha.farmvill.dao.DivisionDaoImp">
>         <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
>     </beans:bean>
>     <beans:bean id="divisionService" class="com.asha.farmvill.service.DivisionServiceImp">
>         <beans:property name="divisionDao" ref="divisionDao"></beans:property>
>     </beans:bean>
>     <context:component-scan base-package="com.asha.farmvill" />
>
>
>
>     <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
>         <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernate5AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
>     </beans:bean>
> </beans:beans>
> ```

But it does not show any error. 
**Here is my model:**

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name = "division")
    public class Division implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name="id")
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name="name")
        private String name;
```

**My table:**

```
    CREATE TABLE public.division
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  name character varying(20) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT division_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Why are you using query ?

Comment: then what should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 -

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void updatedivision(Division p) {
       Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
       session.saveOrUpdate(p);
       session.flush();
}
```

Solution 2 -

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public void updatedivision(Division p) {
    Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    tx = session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("update Division set name =:name where id = :id ");
    query.setParameter("name", p.getName());  
    query.setParameter("id", p.getId());
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
    if(result > 0){          
        System.out.println("Division updated successfully, Division Details=" + p.getName());
    }
    tx.commit();
}
```

Comment: Where I should add this?

Comment: use query where you can't achieve the functionality via hibernate build in methods

Comment: error: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement, in 1st way

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using query to update the table, you can use session object's saveOrUpdate method like this

```
session.saveOrUpdate(p);
```

If your use case is not to write a query.This will either create a new row in the table or update the existing row. You don't need to use query here.

Comment: When I did this, a new data is entered. But Table is not updated.

Comment: If you give the Id as the same in the table, it will update the value, else it will create a new row.